# Is it possible to use LINQ to select records based on a column value and insert those records into the collection in a specific order?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a collection of records in a Questions table that are linked to each other by a column which creates a waterfall effect (if you will) of questions and answers. An example would be if the user answers a question: How old are you? (and the answer is over 18)

Then the system will request that an additional question is asked, like, *Are you married?* and maybe *do you have children?* And if their answer is *Yes* to being married and *yes* to children, then more questions could be branched off from each answer. This I have working quite well. The complexity comes when I want to join the data together for display/reporting.

Here is an example of the stored data.

[image: Excel Example of Data]

And I store the section's in a separate table:

```
    public int QSetSecId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am looking for a lambda or linq expression to get all the records for Section 95 and if there are `ReferalQSetSecId` with 95, then include those records. And if those included records have `ReferalQSetSecId`'s, then include those records as well. And so on.

I have attempted several permeations of Where and Select statements but I can only seem to get one or two levels and I can only insert the records in at the end.

If I were to manually do this (to three interations) this is what the code would look like:

```
    var clientAnswerReportList1 = await _context.ClientAnswer.Where(x => x.ClientTaxQuesSubId == clientTaxQuesSubid && x.QSetSecId == qSetSecId).ToListAsync();
    foreach (var item1 in clientAnswerReportList1)
    {
        await buildClientAnswerList.AddAsync(item1);
        if (item1.ReferalQSetSecId != 0)
        {
            var clientAnswerReportList2 = await _context.ClientAnswer.Where(x => x.ClientTaxQuesSubId == clientTaxQuesSubid && x.QSetSecId == item1.ReferalQSetSecId).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var item2 in clientAnswerReportList2)
            {
                await buildClientAnswerList.AddAsync(item2);
                if (item2.ReferalQSetSecId != 0)
                {
                    var clientAnswerReportList3 = await _context.ClientAnswer.Where(x => x.ClientTaxQuesSubId == clientTaxQuesSubid && x.QSetSecId == item2.ReferalQSetSecId).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item3 in clientAnswerReportList3)
                    {
                        await buildClientAnswerList.AddAsync(item3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        return buildClientAnswerList;
```

Comment: can you share the attempt please?

Comment: So based on the sample data, what is the input and what is the expected output? Also, do you have this working with traditional non-Linq code?

Comment: Hi Sajid and Rufus, my attempt has partially worked but does not go deep enough into the records. What I did was look through the first sect of questions, if one of the referalids existed in the question, then I nested another loop in that loop and repeated the process. However, the code is very slow (as there are thousands of records and the depth of the filter goes only as far as the nuber of nested loops I include. What it does not solve is ordering the questions with each other for display. Honestly, the code is rudimentary at best.

Comment: EF Core requires you to explicitly `include` relational entities. But there are some ways to code around this 'limitation', but they are all solutions that don't scale and don't perform really well. My advice would be to reconsider your relationships and create a structure that is easier to understand, and easier to query.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for your feedback. The issue with adding a relationship or foreign key is that I start getting cyclical issues during management, eg delete etc. Now I know I can turn this off and am exploring this. The crux of the issue is poor planning on my part. We are so far into the project that making structural changes now will set me back a bit. I am exploring your idea now and will see if I can come up with some proposed solutions for comment by the community.

Comment: Hi Sajid and Rufus, I have updated the post with my code attempts which would work if there are only three levels of questions. As you can imagine the code is pretty slow with very large data sets.

Comment: You need recursive code, either by a recursive method or (better) some sort of a `while` loop. LINQ isn't recursive in itself.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks, that is pretty much what I have done and it goes to 8 iterations. It is not pretty but it does the job. I just thought perhaps there was a better way of doing it. I will be testing the code with a large data set on Monday. Here's me hoping it holds up.